# How to sum up values from a javascript object?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following values in an array which I am trying to get the sum of it. This is how it looks like from the chrome developer tools

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]0: {ID: 1, ProductName: " New phone 1", Price: "€ 600"}1: {ID: 3, ProductName: " New phone 2", Price: "€ 1000"}2: {ID: 4, ProductName: " New phone 3", Price: "€ 400"}length: 3__proto__: Array(0)
```

I would like to get the prices of each Item and compute a sum of all the values. I getting these values from an Api and it could sometimes be more items or less. Currently this is how I am getting the values

```
function setTotalPrice() {
    fetch("http://localhost:1234/api/Product")
        .then(response=>response.json())
        .then(data => {
            data.forEach(element => {
                console.log(element.Price)
            });
        })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get the number from the `Price` string ([split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)) and sum them using [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const data = [
    { ID: 1, ProductName: 'New phone 1', Price: '€ 600' },
    { ID: 3, ProductName: 'New phone 2', Price: '€ 1000' },
    { ID: 4, ProductName: 'New phone 3', Price: '€ 400' },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, val) => acc + parseInt(val.Price.split(' ')[1], 10), 0);

console.log(result);
console.log('€ ' + result);
```

If API can return a floating point number for `Price`, need to use [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead:

```js
const data = [
    { ID: 1, ProductName: 'New phone 1', Price: '€ 600.25' },
    { ID: 3, ProductName: 'New phone 2', Price: '€ 1000' },
    { ID: 4, ProductName: 'New phone 3', Price: '€ 400.10' },
];

const result = data.reduce((acc, val) => acc + parseFloat(val.Price.split(' ')[1]), 0);

console.log(result);
console.log('€ ' + result);
```

Comment: why not parseFloat?

Answer (score 0):

```
const sum = data
  .map(({ price }) => {
    const digitsStartIndex = price.substring(price.findIndex(' ') + 1);
    return parseFloat(digitsStartIndex, 10)
  })
  .reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
console.log(`€ ${sum}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `reduce` with a little bit of regex `/\d+/`

```js
let data = [
    { id: 1, product: 'phone 1', price: '€ 400' },
    { id: 3, product: 'phone 2', price: '€ 3000' },
    { id: 4, product: 'phone 3', price: '€ 600' },
];

let sum = data.reduce((a,{price}) => a + Number(price.match(/\d+/)),0);

console.log(sum);
```